# SQL -How to add an auto incremental id in a auto generated temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like below and it generate a temporary table automatically based on parameter. So, the number of column of this table can be vary. Now , i need to add an auto incremental id column into this table.How i do it?

```
SELECT @SourceFields INTO ##StoreSourceInfo FROM testdb.dbo.@SourceTable
```

Note: 1) Number of source field & name of table pass using the parameter `@SourceFields & @SourceTable`.
      2) So, the number of column can be vary on ##StoreSourceInfo table.

**Current Result:**

`select * from ##StoreSourceInfo` shows only the available column.

**Expected Result:** 
`select * from ##StoreSourceInfo` query will show **an additional auto incremental id column** & all rest of the column available in the temp table.

Hope you get me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about an `ALTER TABLE` statement for your temp table?

Comment: Solution is: SELECT IDENTITY(int, 1,1) AS id, @SourceFields INTO ##StoreSourceInfo FROM testdb.dbo.@SourceTable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the identity function. See the link for an example.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189838.aspx

Comment: Thanks.the solution is: SELECT IDENTITY(int, 1,1) AS id, @SourceFields INTO ##StoreSourceInfo FROM testdb.dbo.@SourceTable

Comment: WARNING! This ACTUALLY creates a new table in your database! If you want the table to be REALLY temporary, then prefix its name with '#' as seen in the more upvoted solution.

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT
  IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS id
INTO #Temptable
FROM User
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use row_number function

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by T.field1) rownum
, T.field1, T.field2 into #temp1 
from @Table T
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to try with following query to get your excepted result to add a extra auto increment column :

```
SELECT 
    IDENTITY(INT, 1,1) AS Rank, 
    @SourceFields 
INTO 
    ##StoreSourceInfo 
FROM 
    testdb.dbo.@SourceTable
```

Means apply `IDENTITY` function...