# EntityFramwork and identity generated by trigger

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2014

In my company we're going to create a new application, based on an existing Database. During the process of building the new application we will have both applications (the old and the new one) used in production environment connected to the same database structure.

For this time we can't make major changes to the database structure without having a lot of work to refactor the old application (where the source code is just a big mess)

Now to my problem:
A lot of tables do not have auto generated primary keys. In the old application there are create with something like:

```
  SELECT MAX([id]) as id FROM [tablename];
  var new id = id + 1;
```

To have a good performance on the new application, we don't wanted to generate the new identity in code (We are using EntityFramework 6). Instead we created a trigger to generated the id.

No the problem is, that i cant get the generated id into my entityFramework object. Refreshing the context does not help because there is no other identical criteria on the dataset that i could use to reselect it.

my idea is to use the storeGeneratedPatter.Identity to bring the id back to entityFramwork. But for that case i need the @@IDENTITY variable to be set inside of my trigger.

Is there a possibility to do something like:

```
    SET @@IDENTITY = @id
```

inside of an INSTEAD OF INSERT Trigger?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19270460/261050) (with a specific identity value) to create a value for `@@IDENTITY` in a trigger? It will be the identity value of the temp table, not the actual table that you are inserting, but maybe EF won't notice that.